# Вложение шапки в карман

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда мы раздеваемся в гардеробе, мы шапку просовываем в рукав, всовываем? Можно ли сказать "вложить шапку во внутренний карман / рукав"?

Answer (score 1):

В гардеробе мы обычно **кладём** некоторые вещи в рукав или в карман. Можно и *засунуть*, но это будет означать небрежность - случайно или наспех выбранное для предмета место. "Вкладывание" ("вложение") имеет более узкий смысл: *вкладывают* что-либо не только "внутрь"; зачастую предмет занимает предусмотренное для него место (вложить меч в ножны, деньги в банк, инструмент в футляр), порой имеющее или принимающее (вложить камень в руку) форму предмета.

Comment: А если неопределенная форма? Положить шапку в рукав?